# What is the issue with this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title says.. I cant find an error in this query but still its not working the way it should work

```
SELECT  column_1, column_2, column_3  
from `table_1`  
WHERE   `column_4` = '3'  
order by id limit 1,(count(select table_name from information_schema.tables))
```

Please help

Its giving this error

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(count(select table_name from information_schema.tables))' at line 1

This also not working

```
SELECT  column_1, column_2, column_3  
from `table_1`  
WHERE   `column_4` = '3'  
order by id limit 1,(select count(table_name) from information_schema.tables)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `(count(select table_name from information_schema.tables))` part? As the error message says: that's not valid SQL.

Comment: What i read from the sql manual. It does allow sql query within sql query. Why isnt it working here?

Comment: The argument to `COUNT()` isn't a SQL query.

Comment: @Barmar I think it is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: You still haven't explained what you're actually trying to accomplish. It looks like you're trying to count the number of tables, but it really just doesn't make sense as written. Are you trying to execute two completely separate queries in one go?

Comment: @Matt Ball... I m trying to experiment and use an sql query in other sql query... which apparently for some reason i cant achieve...Happy with the reasoning ?? Now come up with some good answer

Comment: I already gave you the answer, why should he do anything? @MattBall Based on his other question, he seems to be experimenting with the ways that queries can be combined to produce SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Everything after `limit 1` (including the comma) is illegal syntax.

Comment: The comma is OK, you just need a valid expression after it.

Comment: Small mistake, after the comman needs a constant, not an expression.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL requires the parameters to the `LIMIT` clause to be integer constants, not expressions. If you want to calculate them, you have to use prepared statements or dynamic SQL. An example from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) is:

```
SET @skip=1; SET @numrows=5;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```

So for your case, you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(table_name) INTO @tables FROM information_schema.tables;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT  column_1, column_2, column_3  
                   from `table_1`  
                   WHERE   `column_4` = "3"
                   order by id limit 1, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @tables;
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar...Can you please also review this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252442/crafting-a-query-for-blind-sql-injection